# how to convert enums to display name and value to json

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, enums

```
    public static class HtmlEnumExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString EnumToString<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>();
            var enumDictionary = values.ToDictionary(value => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value));

            return new MvcHtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(enumDictionary));
        }
    }
 <script>
     var assetStatusEnum = @(Html.EnumToString<AssetStatusEnum>())
     var assetStatusEnum ={"Free":0,"Reserved":1,"Inactive":2,"UnderMaintenance":3}
    </script>
public enum ProjectState
    {
        [Display(Name = "bianji")]
        Wait = 0,
        [Display(Name = "tongguo")]
        Pass = 1,
        [Display(Name = "jujue")]
        Reject = 2,
        [Display(Name = "shangchu")]
        Deleted = 3
    }
```

this is the extension method for HtmlHelper, How can I get enums customattribute display name and value 
`var assetStatusEnum = [{"name":"bianji","value":"0"},{"name":"tongguo","value":"1"}...]`
How to modify the extension method for HtmlHelper to achieve what I want? I want to implement the EnumToString overload to accept a displyname parameter and return value.

Answer (score 3):

Try to flatten your `values` like below with `.Select` predicate,

```
var enumDictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
    .Cast<T>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        name = x,
        value = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x.ToString()))
    })
    .ToList();
```

If you want to get name inside `Display` attribute then you can use below,

```
var enumDictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
    .Cast<T>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        name = x.GetType().GetMember(x.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().GetName(),
        value = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x.ToString()))
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Note:** You need to import some namespaces to your program like

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: How can I get enums customattribute display name and value

Comment: answer updated. use second snippet to get `Display` name of enum member :)